# How to make MudSelect show text of selected option instead of value?

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

```
<MudSelect MultiSelection="true" @bind-SelectedValues="ViewModel.Model.GlobalSalaryAccessUserIds">
                @foreach (var salaryAccessUser in ViewModel.GlobalSalaryAccessUsers)
                {
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@salaryAccessUser.Id">@GenerateSalaryAccessUserDisplayString(salaryAccessUser)</MudSelectItem>
                }
            </MudSelect>
```

Now instead of string which generates in `GenerateSalaryAccessUserDisplayString` it shows a value of the option, which is id, when I've selected a few of them . How can I change it to show the generated string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.
You can use `ToStringFunc` attribute of `MudSelect`.

In your code behind you have to declare a `Func<'your option value type',string>` and apply it to `ToStringFunc`.

My case:

```
<MudSelect MultiSelection="true" @bind-SelectedValues="ViewModel.Model.GlobalSalaryAccessUserIds" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Label="Manager" ToStringFunc="ToStringConverter">
                    @foreach (var salaryAccessUser in ViewModel.GlobalSalaryAccessUsers)
                    {
                        <MudSelectItem Value="@(salaryAccessUser.Id)">@GenerateSalaryAccessUserDisplayString(salaryAccessUser)</MudSelectItem>
                    }
                </MudSelect>

// ------------ Code behind ------------------
protected Func<int, string> ToStringConverter;

// Have to initialize it separately
protected override Task OnInitializedComponentAsync()
{
    ToStringConverter = GenerateSalaryAccessUserDisplayString;

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private string GenerateSalaryAccessUserDisplayString(int salaryAccessUserId)
    {
        var salaryAccessUser = ViewModel.GlobalSalaryAccessUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == salaryAccessUserId);

        return $"{salaryAccessUser.FirstName} {salaryAccessUser.LastName}";
    }
```